# CSS background class not working

Tags: html, css

I have a problem, my class not display in the parent DIV.

**css code**

```
.div.red {
color:red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="div red">Here content</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly

Comment: why calling class div? div is not a class, red is a class so you should call ".red" in your css

Comment: @FrankW. The OP has both `div` and `red` as classes. It's not a great idea as it can cause confusion with missing the `.` in the CSS on quick scan, but is valid.

Comment: Maybe i expressed myself wrong. Div shoulden't be a class :P because of the reason you are giving... confusion.

Comment: You should try not to create class names that are already present as element names (like `div`, `a`, `li`, etc). It creates confusion -- "Maybe they mean the div element, not a class?"

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @krillgar. It is valid, but not recommended.

As for the question:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="div red">
  <div class="some_content"> Some Content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.div, .red{
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: red;
}

.some_content{
  background:blue;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  color: white;
}
```

**Troubleshooting tips**: Inspect your element in your browser and see if the css classes are being applied. Maybe classes are being applied, but missing width and height.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/psqm9tbw/

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS styling is working as you posted it. If you want to change the background color instead of the text color you need to use background-color: red;.

ex.

```
.div.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the text color not the background see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/16q2xr8k/1/

```
.div.red {
color:red;
background-color: blue;
}
```